# Get rid of anomaly appearing in the colour legend (ggplot2)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

[image]

You can notice that in the colour scale, for the first item (LTE only: the red-dashed line), there is an anomaly in the dashed line. Somehow the line gets thinner before the actual whitespace.

This anomaly disappears when I don't plot he data of with the blue color:

[image]

Note that the dashed line looks OK now.

I use the following code to plot the data:

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_summary( data = cellBlocksUtilizationUl_lteOnly, aes(x=roundedRealNumVehicles/2, y=(value), colour=as.factor(1),  lty=as.factor(1) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1 ) +
  stat_summary( data = cellBlocksUtilizationUl_clust, aes(x=roundedRealNumVehicles/2, y=(value), colour=as.factor(2), size=as.factor(clusteringDistance), lty=as.factor(2) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line", alpha=0.80 ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2,1) , name  ="Protocol\nType" , labels=c("LTE only", "LTE4V2X")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = myColors , name  ="Protocol\nType" , labels=c("LTE only", "LTE4V2X")) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.4, 0.7, 1.2, 2, 3, 4, 5) , name = "Clustering\nDistance (m)" , labels=c("100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "550", "600"), guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(colour = myColors[2])) )
```

Comment: /reproducible/ example please

Comment: @rawr added trimmed `dput`s of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain the cause of problem (it seems that in legend two types of sizes are plotted) but you can remove this effect by `override.aes=` and setting `size=` inside the color scale.

```
+ scale_color_manual(values = c("red","blue") , 
          name  ="Protocol\nType" , labels=c("LTE only", "LTE4V2X"),
          guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 1))) +
```